# Why would increase in innodb_buffer_pool_size slow down MySQL?

Tags: mysql, innodb, memory, buffer-pool

5.1.68-cll - MySQL Community Server on CentOS

The system has 32GB of RAM.

I increased innodb_buffer_pool_size from 10240M to 15360M (10GB -> 15GB).

Time taken for a series of identical operations increased from 720 to 822 seconds (14% increase).

This was the result only a single test at each setting. But 4 previous tests performed a few months ago resulted in times between 726 and 740s.

I just tried running it again with 8GB, and the time taken was 719s.

Why would more memory result in a slower process?

EDIT: More details on process

The process that I'm testing involves emptying some tables and rebuilding them from data from existing tables. I'm not sure if it's using `SELECT INSERT` or if it's `SELECT`ing the data, then using PHP to create long `INSERT` statements. If that matters then I can find out.

There are no schema definition changes being made.

Here is the output of `numactl --hardware` while the server is relatively idle:

```
root@server [~]# numactl --hardware
available: 1 nodes (0)
node 0 cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
node 0 size: 32740 MB
node 0 free: 6216 MB
node distances:
node   0
  0:  10
```

And `free -m`

```
root@server [~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32081      25864       6216          0       2591      12791
-/+ buffers/cache:      10482      21599
Swap:        15994         16      15977
```

Edit by RolandoMySQLDBA

Please run this query

```
SELECT
    InnoDBSpace / POWER(1024,1) InnoDB_KB,
    InnoDBSpace / POWER(1024,2) InnoDB_MB,
    InnoDBSpace / POWER(1024,3) InnoDB_GB
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) InnoDBSpace
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE ENGINE='InnoDB'
) A;
```

RESULT:

```
InnoDB_KB InnoDB_MB InnoDB_GB
8413536 8216.34375 8.02377319335938
```

and this one

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_pages%';
```

RESULT:

```
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data
410035
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty
204
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed
826954
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free
99231
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc
15022
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total
524288
```

During running of process:

```
root@server [~]# numactl --hardware
available: 1 nodes (0)
node 0 cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
node 0 size: 32740 MB
node 0 free: 5461 MB
node distances:
node   0
  0:  10
```

and:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32081      26658       5423          0       2603      12948
-/+ buffers/cache:      11106      20975
Swap:        15994         16      15977
```

Comment: How many cores does the DB Server have? If you are not sure, please run `numactl --hardware` and post the output.

Comment: Please post the output of `free -m`

Comment: Were the measurements taken on "cold" database or on "hot" database? It may take time to populate more memory; any benchmark should take place only after the database has ran for a while.

Comment: @ShlomiNoach the database has been in use for months and the server is never off (just occasionally rebooted). I will add some information about the operations the db is performing to my question.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I added them but those were run NOT during the process in question. I can give you the output while the process is running if you want.

Comment: I will like to see that if possible as well. I also asked for two more things. I will insert that into the question.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I added the query results to the question. I can rerun the shell commands during the process tonight.

Comment: Is this a VM or bare metal machine? My guess, it's a VM.

Comment: @ButtleButkus, I'm afraid what you're saying is impossible: for `innodb_buffer_pool_size` changes to take affect, one must restart the MySQL server. So what about it?

Answer (score 3):

From what you gave me thus far

- The CPU has the illustrious task of accessing all 32GB RAM.
- InnoDB's Buffer Pool is 8GB (524288 * 16384)

  - 524288 ([Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total))
  - 16384 ([Innodb_page_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_page_size)))

## InnoDB Architecture

[image]

## CONJECTURE #1

Since InnoDB allocates its buffer pool contiguously, one could only imagine if there is any form of fragmentation of data and index pages among other things in the Buffer Pool. What other things? There are also updates for secondary non-unique indexes posted first inside the Buffer Pool before they are merged into the System Tablespace file (better known as `ibdata1`). Please notice the Insert Buffer within the **`InnoDB Architecture`**.

## CONJECTURE #2

While a larger buffer pool can reduce disk I/O, a buffer pool that's too large may have issues, such as the fragmentation issue I just mentioned.

Perhaps sparse memory, though contiguous, is not a good thing either. I discussed something of that nature back on `Oct 22, 2012` : [How large should be mysql innodb_buffer_pool_size?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27328/how-large-should-be-mysql-innodb-buffer-pool-size/27341#27341)

I noticed the miscellaneous pages ([Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc)) within the buffer pool. That takes up 235 MB (16384 * 15022). Just some overhead for indexing and row locks. Notwithstanding, this can be victimized by a large buffer pool with lots of sizable empty gaps.

## CONJECTURE #3

Data and index pages are not the only things that occupy the Buffer Pool. An annoying neighbor they must share space with is the Insert Buffer. That section of the Buffer Pool contains the changes for all non-unique indexes. Depending on the number of indexes each InnoDB table has, up to half of the Buffer Pool could be used. This should be a good reminder to look over all InnoDB table and remove redundant indexes

Here are other posts that describes how to hunt down redundant indexes and why to get rid of them:

- `Jan 26, 2012` : [MySql - find redundant indexes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11704/mysql-find-redundant-indexes)
- `Dec 10, 2011` : [Do I have duplicate key indexes?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9009/do-i-have-duplicate-key-indexes/9010#9010)
- `Sep 07, 2011` : [MySQL CPU Usage](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5425/mysql-cpu-usage/5494#5494)
- `May 17, 2011` : [Do I need to add a new single column index to a table if a multi-column index on that field already exists?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2784/do-i-need-to-add-a-new-single-column-index-to-a-table-if-a-multi-column-index-on/2785#2785)

**Think about it**: If a table has redundant indexes, INSERTs and UPDATEs to a table will results in [rebalancing tree pages 45% of of the time (in the worst case scenario)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27678/how-badly-does-innodb-fragment-in-the-face-of-somewhat-out-of-order-insertions/27685#27685). Such tree rebalancing with happen multiple times for a table with a lot of indexes. Removing redundant indexes cuts down the time spent writing those changes to the Insert Buffer and in turn, to the Index Pages of each InnoDB table.

Increasing the Buffer Pool Size leaves room for the Insert Buffer to run amok if you have InnoDB tables with too many indexes, especially redundant indexes. Another telltale sign that you need to look for such tables is to run this query:

```
SELECT table_schema,table_name,data_length,index_length
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB'
AND data_length/(data_length+index_length) < 0.8;
```

This will give you a general idea which tables need to have the indexes looked over for redundancy of leading columns.

## EPILOGUE

Keep in mind that the Buffer Pool holds

- Data Pages
- Index Pages
- Insert Buffer for Index Changes
- Adaptive Hash Index
- Opened tables info
- Miscellaneous Overhead
- Refer to the **`InnoDB Architecture`**

Wasted space in a Buffer Pool could take more time to sift through, especially with a single core that is solely responsible for all of RAM.

My advice would be to keep the [innodb_buffer_pool_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) at 10G.

Answer (score 0):

We used to say that innodb_buffer_pool_size should be between 55% and 65% of your total memory. Maybe your system don't have enough memory to work well (because of MySQL stolen all his memory) and your system is always have the priority.

If your system is in trouble, your MySQL Server is going to be in trouble too :)

Comment: Very good point but I should probably have mentioned that the system has 32GB RAM and nothing else intensive running on it. So this is probably not the right answer.